# Best way to trigger a compile-time error if no if-constexpr's succeed?

Tags: c++, type-traits, static-assert, if-constexpr

I have a long series of `if constexpr` statements and would like to trigger a compile-time error if none of them succeed.

Specifically, I have an abstract syntax tree whose result I would like to convert to a specific set of types that I might need.  I have AsInt(), AsDouble(), etc. working, but I need to be able to do so more dynamically based on a supplied type.

As things stand, I've written a templated As() member function, but it's error-checking is clunky.  Specifically, using static assert requires an unwieldy test condition.  Here's a simplified version:

```
template <typename T>
T As() {
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,int>) return AsInt();
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,double>) return AsDouble();
  ...
  if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,std::string>) return AsString();

  static_assert( std::is_same_v<T,int>
                 || std::is_same_v<T,double>
                 || ...
                 || std::is_same_v<T,std::string>,
                 "Invalid template type for As()" );
}
```

Is there a simpler way to trigger the static assert (or equivalent) if all of the conditions fail?

Answer (score 12, accepted):

You need to rewrite your sequence of `if constexpr`s as a chain of `if constexpr ... else if constexpr ...` and have the final `else` clause trigger a compilation error if "reached" (i.e., not discarded). This can be done using the "dependent `false` idiom":

```
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,int>) {
    return AsInt();
} else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,double>) {
    return AsDouble();
} ... else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,std::string>) {
    return AsString();
} else {
    // this is still constexpr, so it will be discarded if any other branch was taken
    static_assert(dependent_false<T>::value, "invalid template type for As()");
}
```

where `dependent_false` is defined as:

```
template <class T> struct dependent_false : std::false_type {};
```

Comment: Could you please explain why `dependent_false` is usefull? Why not just `static_assert(false, "invalid template type for As()");`?

Comment: @Adam Template definition is not allowed to include source that is ill-formed regardless of the template parameter - even if the branch may be discarded. With `dependent_false` the compiler cannot prove that the assert will fail since there may be a specialization of `dependent_false` that defines `value = true`.

Comment: In place, and worked perfectly!  There's definitely a good bit of intuition I still need to develop surrounding templates and constexpr, but this technique makes perfect sense now.

Answer (score 1):

static assert a templated type that is always false

```
if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,int>) {
    return AsInt();
} ...else if constexpr (std::is_same_v<T,double>) {
    return AsDouble(); ... 
} else {
    // this is still constexpr, so it will be discarded if any other branch was taken
    static_assert(!std::is_same<T,T>::value, "invalid template type for As()");
}
```

Similar to brian bi's answer but you don't have to define a new type.